# How can I ignore NUnit tests of a certain category while doing a Jenkins build?

Tags: c#, nunit, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

How can I ignore NUnit tests of a certain category while doing a Jenkins build?
I know how to do this in Team City.  Our production environment uses Jenkins whilst our developers use Team City. I need some tests (database integration) to be ignored while doing our production build on Jenkins.  Any links, tips, or code are certainly appreciated.

```
[Test, Category("DBExclude")]
public void WidgetRepository_FindById_ReturnsWidget()
{
   //I should not run on Jenkins
}
```

Thanks All!

Comment: How are you running your tests via Jenkins?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a Windows Batch command to execute the NUnit tests as part of the Jenkins job, you may simply use the command-line option "/exclude" on the category you've assigned to the test. For the example you've given, the command would be something akin to...

```
nunit-console /exclude:DBExclude nunit.tests.dll
```

And, just for the record, you can do it the other way and select to run tests WITH a certain category as opposed to only those WITHOUT by using the following (again, making use of your example):

```
nunit-console /include:DBExclude nunit.tests.dll
```

NUnit has documentation that details these options and more here: [NUnit Documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6)